# How to delete Ooxml added to a content control in word document using contentControl.insertOoxml() from office.js

Tags: ms-word, office-js, add-in, office-addins, office-js-helpers

So I wanted to add comments in a word document using Office.js. I have used the contentControl.insertOoxml() to add xml into the document. Now I want to delete this added comment (Ooxml). Is there any Office.js api to achieve this ?

Comment: A `Comment` is a very specific thing in a Word document; it's not clear how you're using the term. It would help if you would provide a [mcve] so that people can understand more exactly what you're doing. It would also provide a starting point for creating an answer. You can use the [edit] link below the question to add more information. The short answer to "is it possible" is probably yes...

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no direct word js APIs to add/delete comments. As you have added a comment into the content control using contentControl.insertOoxml(), you can do similar thing to replace the content of the content control with new content without comment using the InsertOoxml API.